# How to cache IQueryable result for paging

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

What is the best way to cache Queryable result if every call need to calculate lot of things and return it to client.

**Code Sample**

```
 [Queryable]
 public IQueryable<Car> Get()
 {
    try
    {
    var result=GetCarList();
    //GetCarList() calculation is  taking  around 1 min

    return result.AsQueryable();
    } 
 }

GetCarList()
{
var query = from car in db.CarDetail
            where car.color == "white"
            select car;

//10k records of white cars are selected with out considering makers 
//white is mandatory
foreach (var car in query)
{
  //Processing each record in every call
}
}
```

**Query sample**

First Page

```
localhost/api/Car?$filter=(make eq 'ford')&$orderby=carid desc&$top=10
```

Second Page

```
localhost/api/Car?$filter=(make eq 'ford')&$orderby=carid desc&$top=10$skip=10
```

Third Page

```
localhost/api/Car?$filter=(make eq 'ford')&$orderby=carid desc&$top=10$skip=20
```

Every time each call is taking 1 min even though the calculation is same for current filter. what is the best way to cache this kind of api call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use caching in ASP.NET Web API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811772/how-to-use-caching-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: I saw those options but there caching is based on full url. here every time url is different but filter is same

Answer (score 0):

As the OP explains in his comment, the object to cache is the list returned by the call to `GetCarList();` and the result is always the same.

You can simply store this in Cache, see docs: [Cache Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When you need it, check if it's in cache. If not, create it and store in cache before using (anywhere you want to use it). As the `Cache` is thread safe you will not have concurernty problems by accesing it from different requests.