# How do i enable cache in my RestAPI in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, browser-cache

This is my EmployeeDetailsController.cs

```
namespace EmpApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("")]

    public class EmployeeDetailsController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]

        [Route("Employees")]

        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees()
        {

        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Details/{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<Details> Details(int id)
        {
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("TeamInfo/{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<Team> TeamInfo(int id)
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("DetailsForTeam/{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<Details> DetailsForTeam(int id)
        {
            ;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PostEmp")]
        public void PostEmp([FromBody] Employee cs)
        {

        }
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("PutEmp/{id}")]
        public void PutEmp(int id, [FromBody]Employee cs)
        {

        }
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("DeleteEmp/{id}")]
        public void DeleteEmp(int id)
        {

        } 
    }
}
```

I made an API which has various services.
            Suppose i call api/Employees,after i call api/Details/12 and then when i click GoBack button in browser, api/Employees should not be triggered.
           How do i enable cache for my API.Please tell me the steps as I am new in WebApI.
            Thanks in advance..

Comment: How do you click back on API calls? Please clarify. Your text almost sounds like you want to enable cache but you ask about disabling it.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811772/how-to-use-caching-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: I have edited the question @Sami Kuhmonen

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before your controller declaration as follows:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public class EmployeeDetailsController : ApiController
{
...
}
```