# Is Caching GET requests DISABLED by default in ASP.NET Web API 2?

Tags: angular, caching, asp.net-web-api2

I have an angular 9 app that needs to work with a ASP.NET Web API 2 RESTful backend without any caching happening.

I've put 'Cache-control: no-cache' header on the request coming from the frontend (using Angular's interceptors).

*Am I correct in assuming that ASP.NET Web API 2 does **NOT** cache GET requests by default so I won't need to manually disable caching on the server side?* It would make sense to me since REST is stateless but I need to be absolutely sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Web API 2 does not cache it's output by default.

This answer was just updated the other day it seems, and even though it's "original" web API, web API 2 didn't implement any default caching mechanism either.
[How to use caching in ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811772/how-to-use-caching-in-asp-net-web-api)

It looks like the [github link](https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.CacheOutput) has also been updated to work with web API 2.