# WebApi: disable browser caching of png files

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, browser-cache

I have following WebApi action

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var path = $"C:\\temp\\images\\{id}.png";
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        result.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1);
        result.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            NoCache = true,
            Public = false,
            Private = true
        };
        return result;
    }
```

I call the webapi by dynamically appending this img html element to my html document:

```
<img src="http://localhost/api/mycontroller/5" />
```

However, the browser shows cached image.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911356/setting-http-cache-control-headers-in-webapi

Comment: Can't use just use: [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]